# Commands give problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Minecraft: 1.16.1 version. (Java Edition) I want to give a player a diamond pickaxe that can only destroy stone blocks. I use this command: `/give @p minecraft:diamond_pickaxe{Enchantments:[{CanDestroy:["minecraft:stone"]}]}` All looks fine, you get an enchanted diamond pickaxe but you cannot mine stones or anything else in adventure mode. What's wrong?

Comment: What enchantment are you trying to get? `CanDestroy` is not an enchantment.

Answer (score 2):

You put the `{CanDestroy:[]}` tag in `{Enchantments:[]}`, which is only meant for enchantments. You need to put CanDestroy in it's own seperate NBT tag.

Like this:

```
/give @s minecraft:diamond_pickaxe{Enchantments:[{}],CanDestroy:["minecraft:stone"]}
```

(Remove the "{}" inside Enchantments to remove enchantment.)